# Best way to passing react props through three components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this kind of components tree in my react app. My *header* component includes the *navbar* component which in turn includes *dialog1* and *dialog2*.
So, I was wondering what is the best way to pass the props [opened1, opened2, handleDialog1, handleDialog2] to the dialog components from header (passing via navbar). Can you tell me the optimal solution?

```
     header
       |
     navbar
   |        |
dialog1  dialog2
```

header.js

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Stack } from "@mui/material";
import Navbar from "components/Navbar";

export default function Header() {
  const [opened1, setOpened1] = useState(false);
  const [opened2, setOpened2] = useState(false);

  const handleDialog1 = () => {
    setOpened1(!opened1);
  };
  const handleDialog2 = () => {
    setOpened2(!opened2);
  };

  return (
    <Stack>
      <Button onClick={handleDialog1}>my first button</Button>
      <Button onClick={handleDialog2}>my second button</Button>
      <Navbar />
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

navbar.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { Typography, Stack } from "@mui/material";
import Dialog1 from "components/Dialog1";
import Dialog2 from "components/Dialog2";

export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <Stack>
      <Typography>lorem ipsum</Typography>
      <Typography>lorem ipsum</Typography>
      <Typography>lorem ipsum</Typography>
      <Dialog1 />
      <Dialog2 />
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

dialog1.js (dialog2.js is an equal component but with different numbers)

```js
import React from "react";
import { Typography, IconButton, Dialog, DialogTitle } from "@mui/material";

export default function Dialog1() {
  return (
    <Dialog open={opened1} onClose={handleDialog1}>
      <DialogTitle>
        <Typography>my first dialog</Typography>
        <IconButton onClick={handleDialog1} />
      </DialogTitle>
    </Dialog>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the Dialogs to be inside the Nav bar? Dialog elements by default draw on top of everything, so that level of nesting isn't needed.

Comment: cause i have to move them position based on the navbar container

Comment: So not true dialogs...
Have you thought about just building the dialogs at the top level and passing them in as props?

Answer (score 1):

First of all make Dialog more generic

```
import React from "react";
import { Typography, IconButton, Dialog as MuiDialog, DialogTitle } from "@mui/material";

type DialogProps = {
    opened: boolean;
    handleDialog: () => void;
    title: string;
}

export default function Dialog({opened, handleDialog, title}: DialogProps) {
    return (
        <MuiDialog open={opened} onClose={handleDialog}>
            <DialogTitle>
                <Typography>{title}</Typography>
                <IconButton onClick={handleDialog} />
            </DialogTitle>
        </MuiDialog>
    );
}
```

And then you can add children to Navbar

```
import React, {PropsWithChildren} from "react";

export default function Navbar(props: PropsWithChildren) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
            <h3>lorem ipsum</h3>
            <h3>lorem ipsum</h3>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Finally pass dialogs as children - this way you dont need to pass any props down. I suppose in your case its a good decision, but in more complex situations with lot nested components you can think of using state managers. React contexts is usually used for global app contenxt like app language or authentificated user

```
export default function Header() {
    const [opened1, setOpened1] = useState(false);
    const [opened2, setOpened2] = useState(false);

    const handleDialog1 = () => {
        setOpened1(!opened1);
    };
    const handleDialog2 = () => {
        setOpened2(!opened2);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleDialog1}>my first button</button>
            <Button onClick={handleDialog2}>my second button</Button>
            <Navbar>
                <Dialog opened={opened1} handleDialog={handleDialog1} title="my first dialog" />
                <Dialog opened={opened2} handleDialog={handleDialog2} title="my second dialog" />
            </Navbar>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a context and using the [useContext](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usecontext.asp) hook. It is a more manageable approach than passing props and requires less implementation than redux.

Here's the context with your buttons integrated:

```
import { FC, createContext, useState } from "react";

export type FilterContextType = { 
    opened1: boolean;
    opened2: boolean;
};

export const FilterContext = createContext<FilterContextType | null>(null);

export const FilterProvider: FC<{children: any}> = 
    ({children }) => {

    const [opened1, setOpened1] = useState(false);
    const [opened2, setOpened2] = useState(false);

    return (
        <FilterContext.Provider value={{opened1: opened1, opened2: opened2}}>
            <div>
                <Button onClick={() => setOpened1(!opened1)}>my first button</Button>
                <Button onClick={() => setOpened2(!opened2)}>my second button</Button>
            </div>
            {children}
        </FilterContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Then you would wrap you child components in Header component:

```
return (
    <Stack>
        <FilterProvider>
            <Navbar />
        </FilterProvider>
    </Stack>
  );
```

And then use it in any child components:

```
const {opened1, opened2} = useContext(FilterContext) as FilterContextType;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the props all the way down manually, but that can be tedious. To avoid this prop drilling for a large amount of nesting, you can use a context.

Below is an example of how you could implement this (with some unchanged code omitted for brevity).

`header.js`:

```
import { useState, createContext } from 'react';
// ...
export const DialogContext = createContext(null); // you can also move this to a separate file
// ...
export default function Header() {
    // ...
    
    return (
        <DialogContext.Provider value={{opened1, handleDialog1, opened2, handleDialog2}}>
            <Stack>
              <Button onClick={handleDialog1}>my first button</Button>
              <Button onClick={handleDialog2}>my second button</Button>
              <Navbar />
            </Stack>
        </DialogContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

`dialog1.js`:

```
// ...
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { DialogContext } from './header.js';
export default function Dialog1() {
    const {opened1, handleDialog1} = useContext(DialogContext);
    return (
        <Dialog open={opened1} onClose={handleDialog1}>
          <DialogTitle>
            <Typography>my first dialog</Typography>
            <IconButton onClick={handleDialog1} />
          </DialogTitle>
        </Dialog>
    );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I suggest u look into react state management either with the default hooks or with  libraries like redux or zustand

Comment: Add this kind of suggestion into comment instead of adding answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).